# What are the differences between socket polling mechanisms of kqueue and epolling?

Tags: linux, freebsd, socket

kqueue socket polling mechanism is used in FreeBSD and epolling in Linux. I would like to know what are the differences between the two mechanisms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kqueue is more general, and more complex than epoll.  Source: http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~sangjin/2012/12/21/epoll-vs-kqueue.html